# add numbers from x to y visual basic

Tags: vb.net, loops

I want to display addition of number from x to y in a label, i.e. 26 + 27 + 28
+ 29 + 30 = 140.

Right now lbl3 displays: 26 + 30 = 140. I would like it to display 26 + 27 + 28 + 29 + 30 = 140.

This what i have so far.

```
    Dim startingNum As Integer = Val(txtbx1.Text)
    Dim endingNum As Integer = Val(txtbx2.Text)
    Dim totalNum As Integer = (endingNum - startingNum) + 1
    Dim totalSum As Integer = (totalNum / 2) * (2 * startingNum + (totalNum - 1))

    For count As Integer = startingNum To endingNum Step 1

        Me.lbl3.Text = startingNum & " + " & count & " = " & totalSum

    Next count
```

Comment: Each time the program does `lbl3.Text = startingNum & " + " & count & " = " & totalSum` it *overwrites* the value of `lbl.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Linq to solve this :

```
' parsing/validation omitted
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range (startingNum, endingNum - startingNum + 1)

' will resolve to a call to String.Concat
lbl3.Text = String.Join(" + ", numbers) & " = " & numbers.Sum ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
    Dim startingNum As Integer = Val(txtbx1.Text)
    Dim endingNum As Integer = Val(txtbx2.Text)
    Dim totalNum As Integer = (endingNum - startingNum) + 1
    Dim totalSum As Integer = (totalNum / 2) * (2 * startingNum + (totalNum - 1))
    Dim result as String = startingNum

    For count As Integer = startingNum + 1 To endingNum Step 1
        result = result & " + " & count
    Next count
    Me.lbl3.Text = result & " = " & totalSum
```